# Template to create std::tuple with N args of type T

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a meta-function that creates an `std::tuple` with `N` args of type `T`, so that, for example:

```
my_meta_function<4, int>::type
```

would produce:

```
std::tuple<int, int, int, int>
```

Or:

```
my_meta_function<2, std::string>::type
```

would produce:

```
std::tuple<std::string, std::string>
```

So far, what I've come up with is:

```
template <std::size_t N, class T, class... Args>
struct my_meta_function
{
    typedef typename my_meta_function<N - 1, Args..., T>::type type;
};

template <class... Args>
struct my_meta_function<0, Args...>
{
    typedef std::tuple<Args...> type;
};
```

I'm not quite sure if I have the template recursion correct here, but with GCC 4.7.2, when I try to instantiate this template, the compiler fails, with the error message:

```
test.cpp:13:8: internal compiler error: in process_partial_specialization, at cp/pt.c:4414
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
```

**Question:** Am I doing this correctly?  Is GCC 4.7.2 simply buggy at this point?  Or am I coding this incorrectly?

Comment: _'Is GCC 4.7.2 simply buggy at this point?'_ GCC isn't that good on c++11 features up to version 4.8 :/ ...

Comment: I've closed the question as dupe. If you have any questions or doubt or you feel like it wasn't fair, feel free to mention me (with `@jefffrey`) and let me know. :)